# How to speed up HTML video on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a website and it has a slider that contains a video tag. It worked on desktop well but it's so slowly on mobile.

In mobile, it's playing smaller(MB) video but it's so slowly. The problem website is https://www.drapebutik.com/

What can I do to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

I would compress the video or use a caching mechanism, this way it would require fewer resources to load and be processed efficiently.

Comment: For further improving quality of Q&A at SO, I'd recommend to ask them to provide more details in the question itself before answering (see [mcve]; think of this like "what other readers will get from this question if the link in it gets broken?"), but thanks for trying to help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are loading all assets on page load making the total size almost 40mb. I would implement some sort of lazy loading of images and videos outside of the viewport. Also if you use Vimeo for serving your videos you would get the added benefit of adaptive bitrate.